# Как прочитать бинарные данные из файла в Lua?

Tags: lua

Я делаю первый свой веб-сервер на Lua, и сейчас надо отправить картинку, а в браузер приходит только слово PNG и больше ничего.

В C# есть метод `File.ReadAllBytes(path)` он читает все байты из файла. Есть ли подобное в Lua? Всю документацию перерыл, но не нашел. Остановился на `io.open(path,"rb"):read("*all")`.

Comment: ну все правильно, `open("rb")`

Answer (score 1):

Вы всё делаете правильно. Чуть более полная и корректная версия:

```lua
local file = assert(io.open(path, 'rb')) -- Открыть файл с проверкой assert
local data = file:read '*a' -- Прочитать все данные
file:close() -- Закрыть файл
```

После этого в `data` будет находиться содержимое файла байт-в-байт.

Comment: а не file:read ?

Comment: @eri спасибо, ошибся.

Comment: `io.read(), we read a line from the standard `

 а про откуда читаем?

Comment: @eri Да что за день такой, везде облажался :D